# Use of variables in global namespace

Tags: c++

Why should this be an error?

```
int a = 0;
a = 42;

int main()
{
}
```

A possibe match for this behavior i could find:

> (3.4.1/4) A name used in global scope, outside of any function, class
>   or user-declared namespace, shall be declared before its use in global
>   scope.

Could this be a defect in standard?

Comment: No, it's not a defect to the standard. The part you quote means you need to have declarations for all the names you want to use _before_ you use them. It doesn't mean you can do whatever you want at global scope.

Comment: What does it mean by before you *use* them in global scope?

Comment: `struct A {}; A foo();` The name `A` is used in the declaration of `foo()`.

Comment: @user974191, you can use it as follows: `int b = a + 1;`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int a = 0; //it is a declaration (and definition too) statement
a = 42;    //it is an assignment statement
```

The second line is the cause of error, for it is an assignment statement.

At the namespace-level, only declaration and definition statements are allowed. Assignment-statements are not allowed at namespace level.

And by *"shall be declared before its use in global scope"* (from the spec's quotation)  means the following:

```
int a = 42;

int b = 2 * a; //a is being used here

int c = a + b; //both a and b are being used here
```

If you define *type* instead, then:

```
struct A {}; //definition of A

struct B { A a; }; //a is declared as member of B 
                   //(which means, A is being "used") 

void f(const A&, const B&); //both A and B are used in the declaration of f
```

Comment: Well, it's an expression statement, to be precise. Assignment is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: If one includes `;`, then it becomes statement.

Comment: Yes, an expression statement.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, expression statement is not an expression though.

Comment: @avakar: Good lord, where did I say it's an expression. I think I named it a statement at least *twice*.

Comment: but it has the word expression in it. Expression statement must be an expression!

Comment: Expression statement is a statement that contains an expression. A money jar is certainly not money.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write an assignment statement like that in the global namespace

it needs to be either in main or in some [member] function

```
int main()
{
  a=42;

  return 0;
}
```